# setter and getter dot notation objective c left and right

Tags: objective-c, setter, getter

I stuck on dot notation for setter and getter

```
self.display = display.text
```

is the left side is called setter and the right side called getter?

please link some references for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Usually everything with a dot notation calls the getter method *except* when it's on the left of an equal sign.

```
self.view = somethingElse.view;
```

is the same as

```
[self setView:[somethingElse view]];
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Objective-C 2.0, a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text
```

... was declared instead as 2 methods like this:

```
- (NSString *) text
{
   return _text;  // _text declared as an instance variable
}

- (void) setText: (NSString *) text
{
   [text retain];
   [_text release];
   _text = text;
}
```

The first one is the getter (it *gets* the ivar) and the second one is the setter (it *sets* the ivar)

So, removing the dot notation what your assignment "expands" out to is:

```
[self setDisplay: [display text]];
```